# Запрос, выбирающий по 2 поля в каждой таблице БД

Tags: mysql

Нужно создать запрос, выбирающий по 2 поля в каждой таблице БД.
Не понимаю, каким образом можно это сделать и можно ли сделать это вообще, так как на ум приходит только вручную перечислить поля и нужные таблицы.

Задание взято из экзамена:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я конечно понимаю, что зная названия таблиц и их поля можно просто перечислить их в SELECT'е, но, не уверен, что это то, что требуется по заданию. Просто хочу узнать, возможно ли запросом получить поля таблицы, не зная их названий? И возможно ли запросом получить все таблицы из БД?

Comment: два любых поля? Два первых поля? Два поля, которые есть в каждой таблице?

Comment: Приведите примеры таблиц и ожидаемый вывод